# How do I get a counter to stop when exiting a modal

Tags: javascript

I am using this code for a countdown to redirect a page after a modal is loaded:

```
    // Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal and begin countdown
btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
(function(){
  var countdown = 5;

  setInterval(function() {
    countdown--;
    if (countdown >= 0) {
      span = document.getElementById("countdown");
      span.innerHTML = countdown;
    }
    // Display 'counter' wherever you want to display it.
    if (countdown === 0) {
        window.location.href= 'https://www.google.com';
        clearInterval(countdown);
    }

  }, 1000);

})();

}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    clearInterval(countdown);
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        clearInterval(countdown);
    }
}
```

I thought that the clearInterval at the bottom would stop the counter if someone just closes the modal, but it doesn't seem to work. What do I need to do to make the counter stop if someone clicks out of the modal or clicks the X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var handle`

at the top, then

```
handle = setInterval(function(...) {...});
```

then

```
clearInterval(handle);
```

Comment: I dont think I understand this answer. I added the var handle at the top but it didn't seem to work.  `var handle = setInterval(function() {
    countdown--;
    if (countdown >= 0) {
      span = document.getElementById("countdown");
      span.innerHTML = countdown;
    }
    // Display 'counter' wherever you want to display it.
    if (countdown === 0) {
        window.location.href= 'https://smb.cyberpolicy.com';
        clearInterval(countdown);
    }

  }, 1000);

})();`

Comment: In both cases inside clearInterval(handle) not clearInterval(countdown)

Comment: This worked now. I had not set the var handle at the top. Thanks!